# Benefit of using a Partial Copy Sandbox instead of Developer Pro?

Tags: sandbox

For a developer, what would be advantages of working in a Partial Copy Sandbox instead of a Developer Pro one?

We will refresh our "Dev Pro" and our "partial Copy" sandboxes. Since we are not a large organization we can develop in a sandbox and directly deploy to production. I am worried about difficulty of copying data from Production to DevPro. I heard it is not an easy task. So, if we just need to use one sandbox before going to Prod.... could it be advantageous to just use a Partial copy instead of a DevPro?

Also, are there any limits we should be aware of, like the number of developers that can use one of them?

Comment: I'd recommend making an [edit] to your question to ask for specific details on the differences between the two sandboxes. As it stands, this question could get closed for being too broad, or primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using full sandboxes is great for development, but those costs are usually outside the budget of most companies that have in-house developers, because they're expensive. For example, adding a full sandbox to our subscription would cost more than my annual salary.

If you're fortunate enough to have a company that can afford a full or partial sandbox for your own personal development, then you'd want to use it so you can always be testing code changes against a copy of live data, which has more realistic qualities than the data most developers and testers use.

It also saves time after every refresh, because you don't have to manually create data or run scripts, which takes time to implement and maintain, and can easily be forgotten after a refresh. In addition, using a large amount of data helps reduce the odds that you'll write code that will fail because of non-selective queries, queries that are poorly filtered (i.e. return far more data than they need to), etc. It allows you to catch more mistakes earlier in the development cycle, often reducing the amount of time it takes to get code to production.

However, odds are you'll want to just use a Developer or Developer Pro sandbox for development, and reserve your partial and full copy sandboxes for Quality Assurance and User Acceptance Testing, unless you're an incredibly small or incredibly wealthy organization with money to burn.

tl-dr; There are a ton of benefits to using live data, so if it's affordable, use the upgraded sandboxes. However, the costs are usually out of the budget for most orgs that are large enough to warrant having a use for sandboxes, so you'll probably need to save your partial and full sandboxes for Quality Assurance and User Acceptance Testing phases of development.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I'm still making edits...